# CodeIgniter "like()" function with % wildcard inside search terms

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, query-builder

Let's say I have function like this:

```
 public function get_list($category = '', $limit = 10, $offset = 0) {
        if (!empty($category))
            $this->db->where('category', $category);
        $search = $this->input->get('search');
        if (!empty($search))
            $this->db->or_like(array('foo_column'=>$search));
        $query = $this->db->get('table_name', $limit, $offset);
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        return $query->result();
 }
```

Produce query as :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE foo_column LIKE '%match something%'
```

As you can see the `%` wildcard can be added in both side, `before` and `after`.

And how if I want to produce like:

```
... WHERE foo_column LIKE '%match%something%'?
```

FYI, I use `str_replace()` function to `change space` to `%` but **codeigniter** always `escape` it with `slash`. 
It Produces query like:

```
... WHERE foo_column LIKE '%match\%something%'
```

This is useful when to search **match another something** with keyword **match something**, and `wildcard` on first and/or after seems doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve such kind of functionality I've updated your code with some different conditions as like.

> Note: Here I've manually placed values of categories and search

```
public function get_list($category = '', $limit = 10, $offset = 0) {
    $category = 'electronics';
    if (!empty($category)) {
        $this->db->where('category', $category);
    }
    $search = 'match something';
    if (preg_match('/\s/', $search) > 0) {
        $search = array_map('trim', array_filter(explode(' ', $search)));
        foreach ($search as $key => $value) {
            $this->db->or_like('foo_column', $value);
        }
    } else if ($search != ''){
        $this->db->like('foo_column', $search);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get('table_name', $limit, $offset);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Here `$search = 'match something'` and this'll generate the query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (`table_name`) WHERE `category` = 'electronics' AND  
`foo_column` LIKE '%match%' OR `foo_column` LIKE '%something%' LIMIT 10
```

If `$search = 'match something another'` then it'll generate the query as

```
SELECT * FROM (`table_name`) WHERE `category` = 'electronics' AND 
`foo_column` LIKE '%match%' OR `foo_column` LIKE '%something%' OR 
`foo_column` LIKE '%another%' LIMIT 10
```

and if `$search = 'match'` the it'll generate the query as

```
SELECT * FROM (`table_name`) WHERE `category` = 'electronics' AND 
`foo_column` LIKE '%match%' LIMIT 10
```

and if `$search = ''` the it'll generate the query as

```
SELECT * FROM (`table_name`) WHERE `category` = 'electronics' LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Very thank you, this is what I'm looking for, maybe it is a good way to add $this->db->group_start() and $this->db->group_end() as of CodeIgniter 3.

Answer (score 1):

the `$this->db->like()` function escapes special characters it contains - including, of course, `%.`

I guess, would be to bypass the problem and use a where function containing your `LIKE` clause:

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('table')
->where("foo_column LIKE %$search%")->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting in 3.0.0 using the "Query Builder" (vs. previous versions "Active Record") there is an additional parameter for `like()` that lets you prevent escaping the match string:

```
$this->db->like('foo_column', '%match%something%', 'none', false)
```

- 3rd param = `'none'` prevents prefix/postfix of additional wildcard chars
- 4th param = `false` prevents escaping of embedded wildcard chars

Note if you use a variable for your match string rather than a literal, you should use `$this->db->escape_like_str($match)` when the 4th param is `false`